# Building a RSS feed with links embedded

Tags: php, mysql, html, xml, rss

Edit: I have this line:

```
$comments = "http://www.kiubbo.com/index.php?action=comments&param=".$articles[$index]->getId();
```

And if I put it here it works out in the title tag, but not on the link or guid tags.

```
fwrite ($fp, "<item>\n");
fwrite ($fp, " <title>$title</title>\n");
fwrite ($fp, " <link>$comments</link>\n");
fwrite ($fp, "<guid>$comments</guid>\n");
fwrite ($fp, "</item>\n");
}
fwrite ($fp, "</channel></rss>\n");
fclose ($fp);
```

For some reason it takes out the "&param" part of the link ($comments).

Thanks everybody.

Comment: What class is $articles initiated from ?

Comment: It the same loop as in the site, it works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be your parser failing to error correct properly. You haven't, for instance, escaped your ampersands. Ask [Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi) what is wrong.

If you want to write an XML file, use an XML tool, don't munge together strings.

Answer (score 1):

If I;ve understood you correctly and your want the link to comments:

```
$comments = "YOUR_WEBSITE_HERE/index.php?action=comments&param=".$articles[$index]->getId();
```

you should probably also use `<link rel="replies"`  for the link, every one loves semantics!

Hope that helps,

Phil

Comment: Thanks it works, I just want also to embedded with the $title so when people click the title link they go directly to the comments page.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I had wrong is I had to change `&` to `&amp;`.